# Win32 WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC background not completely filled

Tags: windows, winapi

I am working on a dialog box that is created and controlled by a host program. The host creates the window and then sends me all the messages, but this means I don't have full access to everything it's doing. (I mention this because it could be contributing to my issue.)

I would like to change the color of an `LTEXT` to red. I am handling the `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` message and it is working where the text is drawn. The problem I'm having is that the rectangle for the `LTEXT` is slightly wider than the length of the text. For the part of the control that does not contain text it is leaving the background white instead of `COLOR_BTNFACE` as I have specified.

Here is the code for my handler. I call it by way of `HANDLE_WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC`.

```
// color message handler
HBRUSH OnControlColor ( HWND hDlg, twobyte dlgItem, HDC hdcCtrl, int type ) override
{
    if ( (dlgItem == ID_MANUAL_EDIT_WARNING) && (type == CTLCOLOR_STATIC) )
    {
        SetTextColor(hdcCtrl, RGB(204, 0, 0));
        SetBkColor(hdcCtrl, GetSysColor(COLOR_BTNFACE));
        return (HBRUSH)GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_BTNFACE);
    }
    return NO;
}
```

It seems like maybe I need to invalidate the entire client rect some way, but I am not sure how to do this. Obviously I could carefully make the rectangle the exact right size in the dialog designer, but this doesn't seem like the safest approach.

Comment: Holy smokes. That fixed it. If you want to write it up as a solution, I'll mark it.

Comment: *"The host creates the window and then sends me all the messages"* - So there's a man-in-the-middle, between the system and your window, that tries to imitate the system?

Comment: Yes, it's a somewhat homegrown way of creating cross platform dialog boxes that allow 3rd parties to extend the functionality of the host. Also I'm pretty sure it's all happening inside the host process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is to *explicitly* select your desired background brush into the control's device context; thus, when its rectangle is drawn, that brush will be used. You can do it with one additional line of code in your handler:

```cpp
HBRUSH OnControlColor ( HWND hDlg, twobyte dlgItem, HDC hdcCtrl, int type ) override
{
    if ( (dlgItem == ID_MANUAL_EDIT_WARNING) && (type == CTLCOLOR_STATIC) )
    {
        SetTextColor(hdcCtrl, RGB(204, 0, 0));
        SetBkColor(hdcCtrl, GetSysColor(COLOR_BTNFACE));
        SelectObject(hdcCtrl, GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_BTNFACE)); // Select the B/G brush
        return (HBRUSH)GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_BTNFACE);
    }
    return NO;
}
```

My one concern here is that you're manipulating object selection in a device context that is 'owned' by another process; this *could* cause issues if the replaced object in that DC is user-created (but that doesn't seem to be so in this case).